# Keep getting delegate = nil UICollectionView

Tags: swift, delegates, uicollectionview

I have two pieces of virtually identical code. One is for a popover view controller collectionView  which works great. I have adapted the same code for "plain vanilla" view controller (embedded in a nav controller), but I can not set the delegate with let delegate = self.delegate. It always returns "nil". Pretty sure I got the storyboard "wiring" set correct (datasource, delegate, etc).

Looked through most of answers and I can't seem to find one that works. Thanks!

Here is the non-functioning code. I am trying here to select a cell and segue to another viewController.

```
protocol FileCollectionViewControllerDelegate {
func fileSelected(controller: FileCollectionViewController, selectedFile: String)
}

class FileCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

 var links : [String] = ["Black", "Dark Gray", "Light Gray", "Blue","Purple", "Green",  "Orange","Red" ]

var delegate: FileCollectionViewControllerDelegate?

@IBOutlet weak var fileCollectionView: UICollectionView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.fileCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


        }

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(fileCollectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1
}
func collectionView(fileCollectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return links.count
}

func collectionView(fileCollectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = fileCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FileCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    cell.fileTitle.text = links[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func collectionView(fileCollectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("delegate", self.delegate)
    if let delegate = self.delegate {   //HERE THE delegate is always nil ???
        print("go to didSelect")
        delegate.fileSelected(self, selectedFile: "silly")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToMainImage", sender: self)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


}



}
```

Thanks. You are the best.

[viewController connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGGgT.png)

[collectionView connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xizE.png)

Object that implements FileCollectionViewControllerDelegate

```
import UIKit

class MainImageViewController: UIViewController, FileCollectionViewControllerDelegate {

var fileName: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//delegate methods

func fileSelected(selectedFile: String) {
    print("got delegate selectedFile ",selectedFile)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToMainImage"{
        let navController = segue.destinationViewController as? FileCollectionViewController

        if let vc = navController {
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: it seems that you might be mistaking the collectionView delegate with the delegate variable of your viewController. Which one did you set in the storyboard?

Comment: Catalina, I am not sure I understand, but I have added screenshots of the connections in the storyboard. Can I set the proper connections programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the screenshot, helped to figure it out what might be wrong. The things you are setting in the storyboard are the `delegate` and `datasource` for the `UICollectionView`. That looks to be right.

In the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method, you are checking for a `delegate` property you have defined in your viewController and from the code you posted it does not seem that you are setting it anywhere.

You need to set `viewController.delegate` to an object of a class that is implementing your  protocol. Since the code does not show any object that is implementing the protocol, I dont know what that object would be so I provide you with a more concrete answer.

If you need more help, just share a bit more about these things that are missing and I'll try to help you more. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Here is the object. All I trying to do  here is segue upon clicking a cell in FileCollectionView and pass some data via the delegate. As I said, I have a popover that functions perfectly with nearly the exact same code. Sorry added code to above.